# recover from that IP sends an email

Tags: php

Is it possible to add a code to retrieve IP of the sender
a customer review?

I feel that something is missing in this variable because I am not able to retrieve the IP with my PHP scripts. For the moment I have:

PHP code:

```
$print("Votre adresse IP est : $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']");
```

And:

```
        // Code for sending mail when a new testimonial has been Added
    if ( $rset && mysqli_affected_rows($link)>0 ) {
        $to         = $useremail;                    
        $subject    = 'Nouveau Témoignage Ajouté';
        $message    = "Témoignage Détails". "\r\n" ;
        $message    .='Nom du client :'.stripslashes( $client_id ). "\r\n" ;
        $message    .='Témoignage :' .stripslashes( $feedback ). "\r\n" ;
        $headers    = 'De:' .$to . "\r\n" ;
        @mail( $to, $subject, $message, $headers );
        $successmsg  =  "Témoignage a été ajouté avec succès.";
    }else if ( mysqli_errno($link)) {
        $errmsg =  mysqli_errno($link);
    }else {
        $errmsg = "Ajout Témoignage échoué.";
    }   
}else{

    if(  $validate != 'true' ) {
        $errmsg = $validate;
    }
}
}
?>
```

issue here
add the function id #checkbox

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function validatefrm() 
{
    var frm = document.addform;
    var x = document.forms["addform"]["emailid"].value;
    var atpos = x.indexOf("@");
    var dotpos = x.lastIndexOf(".");

    var ratingtype = jQuery('.ratingtype').val();
     if (ratingtype == 'custom' ) {
        var rating = jQuery('.customratings');
    } else  if (ratingtype == 'ratings' ) {
        var rating = jQuery('.rating');
    }       
    if ( frm.client_id.value === "" ) {
        alert("Entrez le nom du client pour le Commentaires.");
        frm.client_id.focus();
        return false;
    }

    else if( frm.emailid.value === "" ) {
        alert("Entrez l'adresse e-mail");
        frm.emailid.focus();
        return false;
     }
    else if (atpos<1 || dotpos<atpos+2 || dotpos+2>=x.length) {
        alert("Not a valid e-mail address");
        frm.emailid.focus();
        return false;
    }
    else if ( frm.day.value === "" ) {
        alert("Sélectionnez jour");
        frm.day.focus();
        return false;
    }
    else if ( frm.month.value === "" ) {
        alert("Sélectionnez un mois");
        frm.month.focus();
        return false;
    }
    else if ( frm.year.value === "" ) {
        alert("Sélectionnez Année");
        frm.year.focus();
        return false;
    }

    else if ( frm.proj_desc.value === "" ) {
        alert("Entrez le titre pour le projet ");
        frm.proj_desc.focus();
        return false;
    }       
    else if( frm.companyname.value === "" ) {
        alert("Entrez le nom ou site web entreprise ");
        frm.companyname.focus();
        return false;
    }
    else if( frm.feedback.value === "" ) {
        alert("Entrez Témoignage");
        frm.feedback.focus();
        return false;
    }
    else if( frm.captcha.value === "" ) {
        alert("Enter captcha");
        frm.captcha.focus();
        return false;
    }
    else if (jQuery("#checkbox").prop("checked")==false) {
        alert("Cochez cette case si vous acceptez les termes et conditions.");
        frm.checkbox.focus();
        return false;           
     }

    return true;
}

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    jQuery('.select_wrapper').each(function () {
        jQuery(this).prepend('<span>' + jQuery(this).find('.select option:selected').text() + '</span>');
    });
    jQuery('.select').on('change', function () {
        jQuery(this).prev('span').replaceWith('<span>' + jQuery(this).find('option:selected').text() + '</span>');
    });
});
```

add “name” checkbox and “id” checkbox
code is correct

```
                                <div class="item">
                                <div class="checkbox">
                                    <label>
                                    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" id="checkbox" > En continuant, vous acceptez les <a href="cgu.php"><span class="skin-color">Conditions générales</span></a>.
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                           </div>
```

Thank you

Comment: Is `$print` a variable or are you meaning the PHP `print` function?

Comment: it looks like you wrote that code in MS Word or something cus you're using strange quotes. Try typing it again in a real IDE.

Comment: also, print is a function, not a variable `$print()`

Comment: we did a test
the checkbox,
works

Comment: Please do not vandalize your question after it has been solved. I rolled back those edits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this function for get client IP

```
<?PHP 

function GetIP()
    {
        if ( getenv("HTTP_CLIENT_IP") ) {
            $ip = getenv("HTTP_CLIENT_IP");
        }
        elseif ( getenv("HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR") ) {
            $ip = getenv("HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR");
            if ( strstr($ip, ',') ) {
                $tmp = explode(',', $ip);
                $ip  = trim($tmp[0]);
            }
        }
        else {
            $ip = getenv("REMOTE_ADDR");
        }

        return $ip;
    }


        // Code for sending mail when a new testimonial has been Added
    if ( $rset && mysqli_affected_rows($link)>0 ) {
        $to         = $useremail;                    
        $subject    = 'Nouveau Témoignage Ajouté';
        $message    = "Témoignage Détails". "\r\n" ;
        $message    .='Nom du client :'.stripslashes( $client_id ). "\r\n" ;
        $message    .='Témoignage :' .stripslashes( $feedback ). "\r\n" ;
        $message    .='Votre adresse IP est :' .GetIP(). "\r\n" ;
        $headers    = 'De:' .$to . "\r\n" ;
        @mail( $to, $subject, $message, $headers );
        $successmsg  =  "Témoignage a été ajouté avec succès.";
    }else if ( mysqli_errno($link)) {
        $errmsg =  mysqli_errno($link);
    }else {
        $errmsg = "Ajout Témoignage échoué.";
    }   
}else{

    if(  $validate != 'true' ) {
        $errmsg = $validate;
    }
}
}
?>
```

Comment: before  // Code for sending mail when a new testimonial has been Added      after

Comment: before it, and you must call the function like GetIP(); example using $IPAddress = GetIP();

Comment: function GetIP()
  {
   if ( getenv("HTTP_CLIENT_IP") ) {
    $ip = getenv("HTTP_CLIENT_IP");
   }
   elseif ( getenv("HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR") ) {
    $ip = getenv("HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR");
    if ( strstr($ip, ',') ) {
     $tmp = explode(',', $ip);
     $ip  = trim($tmp[0]);
    }
   }
   else {
    $ip = getenv("REMOTE_ADDR");
   }

   return $ip;
  }
    
  // Code for sending mail when a new testimonial has been Added